# Python - PyQt - matplotlib: drawRectangle method

Tags: python, matplotlib, canvas, pyqt

I'm using the matplotlib `backend_qt5agg` to handle drawing a matplotlib canvas into a qt window. The user can draw rectangles (of the type `matplotlib.patches.Rectangle`) on the plot and I show the rectangle by calling the `canvas.draw()` method. This method could be quite slow if the canvas contains a lot of data, and I would like to speed it up.

Looking for solutions I found in the `backend_qt5agg` manual that a method called `drawRectangle(rect)` exists. Hoping that this method could draw only the patch without redrawing the entire canvas, I tried to call this method using as input the Rectangle patch. So I call `canvas.drawRectangle(my_rect)` instead of calling `canvas.draw()`. This doesn't draw anything.

Unfortunately the `backend_qt5agg` manual is purely documented. So my question is: how does the `drawRectangle` method work and should it perform better than redrawing the entire canvas?

Minimal example (a rectangle is shown when the mouse is clicked and moved inside the canvas) (just change `self.canvas.draw()` with `self.canvas.drawRectangle(self.rect)` inside `on_motion` to look to test the `drawRectangle` method):

```
import sys
import matplotlib
from PyQt5 import QtCore
import PyQt5.QtWidgets as QtW
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg
from matplotlib.patches import Rectangle


class MainWindow(QtW.QMainWindow):

  def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()
    self.setWindowTitle('MyWindow')
    self._main = QtW.QWidget()
    self.setCentralWidget(self._main) 

    # Set canvas properties
    self.fig = matplotlib.figure.Figure(figsize=(5,5))
    self.canvas = FigureCanvasQTAgg(self.fig)
    self.ax = self.fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)
    self.rect = Rectangle((0,0), 0.2, 0.2, color='k', fill=None, alpha=1)
    self.ax.add_patch(self.rect); self.rect.set_visible(False)
    self.canvas.draw()

    # set Qlayout properties and show window
    self.gridLayout = QtW.QGridLayout(self._main)
    self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.canvas)
    self.setLayout(self.gridLayout)
    self.show()

    # connect mouse events to canvas
    self.fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', self.on_click)
    self.fig.canvas.mpl_connect('motion_notify_event', self.on_motion)


  def on_click(self, event):
    if event.button == 1 or event.button == 3:
    # left or right click: get the x and y coordinates
        if event.inaxes is not None:
          self.xclick = event.xdata
          self.yclick = event.ydata
          self.on_press = True

  def on_motion(self, event):
    # draw the square
    if event.button == 1 or event.button == 3 and self.on_press == True:
      if (self.xclick is not None and self.yclick is not None):
        x0, y0 = self.xclick, self.yclick
        x1, y1 = event.xdata, event.ydata
        if (x1 is not None or y1 is not None):
          self.rect.set_width(x1 - x0)
          self.rect.set_height(y1 - y0)
          self.rect.set_xy((x0, y0))
          self.rect.set_visible(True)
          self.canvas.draw() # self.canvas.drawRectangle(self.rect)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtCore.QCoreApplication.instance()
    if app is None: app = QtW.QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = MainWindow()
    app.aboutToQuit.connect(app.deleteLater)
    app.exec_()
```

Comment: From the [source code](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/1ec1a9c4f9bd50bb5a078e7327024c718318bac6/lib/matplotlib/backends/backend_qt5.py#L526) it looks like this function is intended to draw the dotted-line rectangle that is shown when you are zooming in on a portion of the graph in the interactive window.

Comment: Please, add a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @Isma I added an example

Comment: @DizietAsahi Thanks for pointing that out, but it's still not clear to me the use of that method. What is the `rect` input suppose to be?

Comment: @Isma, the rectangle is supposed to be shown when the mouse is pressed and moved inside the canvas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of adding the rectangle yourself you could use the `RectangleSelector` widget that is already included as part of matplotlib.widgets.

Here is an example, you will need to polish it and adapt it to your needs but I hope it will get you going:

```
import sys
import matplotlib
from PyQt5 import QtCore
import PyQt5.QtWidgets as QtW
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg
from matplotlib.widgets import RectangleSelector


class MainWindow(QtW.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle('MyWindow')
        self._main = QtW.QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self._main) 

        # Set canvas properties
        self.fig = matplotlib.figure.Figure(figsize=(5,5))
        self.canvas = FigureCanvasQTAgg(self.fig)
        self.ax = self.fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)
        self.canvas.draw()

        self.rs = RectangleSelector(self.ax, self.line_select_callback,
                                                drawtype='box', useblit=True,
                                                button=[1, 3],  # don't use middle button
                                                minspanx=5, minspany=5,
                                                spancoords='pixels',
                                                interactive=True)

        # set Qlayout properties and show window
        self.gridLayout = QtW.QGridLayout(self._main)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.canvas)
        self.setLayout(self.gridLayout)
        self.show()

        # connect mouse events to canvas
        self.fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', self.on_click)

    def on_click(self, event):
        if event.button == 1 or event.button == 3 and not self.rs.active:
            self.rs.set_active(True)
        else:
            self.rs.set_active(False)

    def line_select_callback(self, eclick, erelease):
        x1, y1 = eclick.xdata, eclick.ydata
        x2, y2 = erelease.xdata, erelease.ydata
        print("(%3.2f, %3.2f) --> (%3.2f, %3.2f)" % (x1, y1, x2, y2))
        print(" The button you used were: %s %s" % (eclick.button, erelease.button))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtCore.QCoreApplication.instance()
    if app is None: app = QtW.QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = MainWindow()
    app.aboutToQuit.connect(app.deleteLater)
    app.exec_()
```

Reference: https://matplotlib.org/examples/widgets/rectangle_selector.html

Comment: Thanks for the example, your solution for selection is quite elegant.

Comment: On the other hand, my question was a bit more general.
For example, after selection I want a rectangle to stay on the canvas, and let's say I want to change rectangle properties (such line or color) depending on other user actions (QPushButton for example). In that case I have to redraw the canvas. My question is still: is it possible to modify that rectangle without redrawing the entier canvas?

Comment: Yes, you can, you were doing it right but you need to pass a list instead of a rect, for example, self.canvas.drawRectangle([x0, y0, x1, y1])

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but if I use `self.canvas.drawRectangle([x0, y0, x1, y1])` instead of `self.canvas.draw()` in my code, it still doesn't draw anything.

Comment: Yes I know. In my example x0, y0 etc.. are real values, given by the mouse event, which work if I draw the canvas with `self.canvas.draw()`, but it dosen't work if I use `self.canvas.drawRectangle([x0, y0, x1, y1])`. Did you test it?

Comment: Yes, I was able to create a rectangle passing a list of values. Maybe there is something wrong with the values you are passing, try with something fixed like [0,0,250,250] you should see a rectangle in the top left corner...

Comment: You are right. The thing is `drawRectangle` is accepting coordinates in the figure frame (not plot coordinates), and in pixel units.
Anyway, the line style of the rectangle cannot be changed, is defined inside the backend. So this drawRectangle method is not what I was looking for. I suppose I should define my own method where I can pass to drawRectangle also some directives.
Thanks for helping